# Replicating growing log files in a near real-time manner over the network

Tags: files, tail, streaming, netcat, replication

I have a server with a bunch of processes writing log files as they run. I need to enable a client host to get a replica of the server-side log files in a near real-time manner. Is there a better way than simply combining tail with netcat?

I was thinking of using tail with netcat on the server side to stream multiple log files through a single connection:

```
tail -F *.log | nc -lk -p 31377
```

While the client side would demultiplex the logs and write them to files:

```
nc serverhost 31377 | demultiplexer
```

Where demultiplexer is simply built around sed, figuring destination filenames from separators inserted by tail on the server side:

```
sed -e 's/==> \(.*\) <==/\1/'
```

Comment: shouldn't you use a `syslog(3)` call, and use system `syslogd` (or `rsyslog.conf`) configuration to broadcast ?

Comment: Cannot change the way log is written by processes on the server, so trying to find a non-intrusive way. Or do you suggest to first tail the log and then to write it with syslog in a separate process?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 tail -f /path/to/logfile.log | xargs -l logger -p local8.info
```

- `xargs -l` will read line by line.
- you have to configure syslog.conf to broadcast though. (replacing `local8` and `info` by proper value)